# Maintain ngRepeat order while bound data changes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, tablesort

I am new to Angular and I am now learning about directives.

I have created a directive that will create a table.
You can sort the table by clicking on the header arrows.
You can also edit/delete a row by clicking on the action button.

[image: Table at default order]

The problem with my table is that when the rows are sorted by some column,
and I edit an item under that column, the table resorts because of the changed data. Thus my currently editting item moves to another row and the current input fields contain a different one.

For example, if I sorted the table by visits, and then I edit a visit data in a row,

[image: Table at editting state]
changes to :
[image: Table resorts when bound data changes]

How can I maintain the current order of the rows during edit,
and only allow resort when I click on the apply button (check) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the model which will be edited during editing. And in your save function, update the actual model in table list.